# Navigation menu with variable

Tags: php, drop-down-menu, menu, html-lists, uinavigationbar

I am trying to implement dashboard kind of system. And having problem with passing variable in navigation menu items.

At first user selects "Workspace Name" from list of workspaces.
That link redirects user to `projects.php?workspaceid=xxxxxx`

Now inside `project.php` , there is sidebar (static) with other options like
`projectsettings.php` , `credentials.php`.

I want to pass variable workspaceid in each sub menu items.
Like `projectsettings.php?workspaceid=xxxxxx` or `credentials.php?workspaceid=xxxxxx`

How can I do so ?

UPDATE :
I think i was quite unclear about question.

At first user comes to `workspaces.php` 
It looks like

![workspace selection table]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBtSm.png

Then for example they select "internet explorer 7" from table.
Link will take them to `project.php?workspaceid=IE7`

It looks like 
![Project dashboard]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EfdK1.png

Here all menus (data menus, data variable, setting.php) should have variable of workspace.

Comment: Can you post some code?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED ANSWER:
You need to set a session once the workspaceid is set

```
<?php
session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['workspaceid'])){
        //do what you need with this info
    }
    else if (isset($_GET['workspaceid'])){
        //lets set the session
         $_SESSION['workspaceid'] = trim(strip_tags($_GET['workspaceid']));
    }
    else {
        //do nothing
    }

//with this method there is no need to pass the workspaceid via url
?>
```

Original answer:

echo the variable in each link you need.

```
<a href="projectsettings.php?workspaceid=<?php echo $_GET['workspaceid']; ?>">link text</a>
```

With get variables you should be careful. I usually check and clean them in the header. So a more advanced way to do this is as follows

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['workspaceid']){
        $workspaceid = trim(strip_tags($_GET['workspaceid']));
    }
?>
```

Then in the link check for isset as well

```
 <a href="projectsettings.php?workspaceid=<?php echo isset($workspaceid)?$workspaceid:''; ?>">link text</a>
```

Comment: Thanks Smith..yes that;s what i am trying to achieve..but problem is taht variable is passes only once from workspace.php to project.php but i want to use same variable everywhere inside that "project.php" dashboard.

Comment: Yehh..i get it. Can i create multiple sessions ? If i want to open 2 projects at same time .

Comment: If you want one user to have multiple projects open you will need to array the workspace id's in the $_SESSION. Then loop them on each page load to get what you need.

Comment: Ohkay..i will look into that.. another quick question..how to pass variables like this https://cloud.google.com/console#/project ..they pass https://cloud.google.com/console#/project/"$projectid"/settings

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['workspaceid']))
    $workspaceid = htmlspecialchars($_GET['workspaceid']);
else
    $workspaceid = '';

$query = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE workspaceid = ?";

if($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)){
     $stmt->bind_param('i',$workspaceid);
     $stmt->execute();
     $result = $stmt->get_result();

     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
         $variablename = $row['columnname']; //put your own in here 
     }

     $stmt->free_result();
     $stmt->close();

}else die("Query failed to prepare");
```

The you can navigate by using `credentials.php?workspaceid=xxxxxx"`

Comment: Thank you for your reply. For workspaceid is not fix. It is variabke coming from database. So structure is workspace selection= > Project dashboard..and inside that dashboard everything is for that dashboard.

Comment: I updated my answer to show you how you can call it using a mysqli statement

Comment: actually i already have predefined menu as as shown above just need to pass project id inside it